# send emails from folder using php on linux without webserver

Tags: php, linux

I have a folder on Linux with emails in it. I also have working library for PHP that sends emails. How is it possible to do so that PHP without webserver runs every minute and checks the folder contents and if it finds emails it sends them?

Comment: Use `cron` to run your script every minute.

Comment: Just set up a cronjob? Do avoid race conditions though: if you have a lot of mail, and a job runs longer then a minute, you might end up with 2 jobs running concurrently & mailing twice. Either avoid the second job (a simple flock is often used), or make sure the process (re)moves the file _before_ sending. However, you could also just install something like exim or postfix and have a real mailserver which takes care of all the nitty gritty details for you.

Comment: Wrikken, thanks! I already have postfix installed, but I'm currently sending emails FROM my application through it, which can take several seconds and the user waits for response. The idea is to set task to send email from the app, but to send emails OUTSIDE the app. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @Wrikken, any comments on my previous comment?

Comment: If you have a _local_ server which takes a long time, you have a problem, and there are several things to consider. First of those would probably be to avoid blacklist checks, spam filtering, and antivirus checks if the sending party is localhost. Usually, it'll be quite quick then, unless you are sending a lot of emails in 1 request.

Comment: If you do send a lot of them in one request, an async solution is probably better indeed. You can do it with the mentioned cronjob, or a continually running deamon (`gearman` is nice). Getting the message to that job can be done with arguments (`gearman`), or some queue storage (files, database, others, take your pick). Your OS probably has a way to install php without a webserver, under Debian & derivatives it would be `apt-get install php5-cli`.

Comment: @Wrikken, I don't have postfix locally, it's on the other machine. Could you please elaborate on the suggestions in your last comment in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21449221/2545680)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your crontab:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/mailscript.php
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to install and configure PHP interpreter somehow?

Comment: Nope. Is the process of installation standart?

Comment: No. I thought that was what you meant by "working PHP library".

Comment: These are just php files with code. Do you know any good read about how to install PHP on Linux without webserver?